# VSCode: Permanently change syntax highlighting on a single file or set of files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a `markdown` file which I would like to permanently highlight using `JSON` syntax.

But I don't want to treat *ALL* `.md` files this way, just a few of them.

Is there a way to accomplish that, so I don't have to manually change the highlighting each time I open the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this with the 'files.associations' setting. For example

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.md": "json"
}
```